# Team City Reports Tab not showing, base path set to target folder

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to display a tab in TeamCity with the Surefire report results, but I can't seem to be able to get report tabs to work.

I can't show images being a new user but my basepath for TeamCity is pointing to "target/surefireReportFolder" which was defined in my pom file as the location of the output " ${basedir}/target/surefireReportFolder".

The index.html file is being generated locally in that folder.

If someone could tell me what I'm missing, it'd be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Can't get it to display on the build results page which is what I was looking to get, but this solution will get it to display on the project page.

http://vanryswyckjan.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/code-coverage-with-teamcity.html